# Mobile browser doesn't support UTF-8 Characterset

Tags: android, browser, utf-8

I have pages in my website which were till now showing only English alphabets. Now i want to show other language characters also (eg, Chinese and Arabic). So i read online and added UTF-8 characterset in the header as below. (i am using cgi-perl for server side coding)

`print $cgi->header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Which was earlier as just `print $cgi->header();`

This worked fine in my laptop browser (mozilla and chrome) its showing all language characters. But in Android default browser (mozilla) its not working. Its downloading the page itself instead of parsing and displaying the content of the page. However, it works in Android chrome browser!

Can anyone guide me as to what should be in the header for the page to work in all browsers?

Comment: You could also try in `<html><head>`: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">`. However in Perl doing at the start `print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";` should work.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv>` is for HTML 4. If you are using HTML 5, use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` instead.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, that is also put. The mobile browser doesnt seem to recognise that header, its ignoring it and not showing special characters. If i give "print $cgi->header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");" its downloading the cgi file (maybe because it didnt recognise the header). Still working on it, will post it if i figure out the solution.